# Target CSS in HTML

Tags: html, css

Good evening first of all. :)

Secondly I have images on my site which will be links to other pages. We wanted the images to start off grey-scale and then when hovered turn to their colors.

So I put the CSS in

```
 img {
    /* filter: url(filters.svg#grayscale); Firefox 3.5+ */
      filter: gray; /* IE5+ */
      -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Webkit Nightlies & Chrome Canary */
      -webkit-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;  
    }
    img:hover {
    filter: none;
      -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.01);
    }
```

So that is great. Except it makes EVERY image on the the website turns black and white until you hover.
So then I was reading about css class and ID. I found this snippet of code

```
<div id="photo-container"> <ul id="img"> <li><a href="#"><img 
src="img url here" alt="sampletext" 
class="photo"></a></li></ul></div>
```

I thought ah cool I will simply change the img in the css and html to something unique. But that didn't do anything. All that happened is my image was displayed with color and everything. So I obviously am not understanding how to have the html call the css. And how to have the css not affect anything but what I call for it too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you use JavaScript with this? It would be much simpler to do

Answer (score 3):

Read about basic CSS selectors here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Selectors

You need to target only certain images with a specific CSS class e.g:

```
.img-greyscale {
    /* filter: url(filters.svg#grayscale); Firefox 3.5+ */
    filter: gray; /* IE5+ */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Webkit Nightlies & Chrome Canary */
    -webkit-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;  
}
.img-greyscale:hover {
    filter: none;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.01);
}
```

then add `class="img-greyscale"` to any image that you need to target e.g:

`<img class="img-greyscale" src="image.jpg">`

Comment: this is the correct way imo but one can also put all the images inside a div with and `id` or a `class` and select them like so `#divID > img`

Comment: Of course, there are a few different ways to solve this problem. The reason why I wouldn't necessarily wrap in a parent id/class is in case you need other non-greyscale images inside that element or you need greyscale images elsewhere in the dom

Answer (score 3):

@Joushua To apply CSS to specific dom element you need to use the class or ID the element in the CSS or you can pass it's parent's class or ID to apply CSS to all the elements contained in given parent element.

If you do not want to change the HTML you posted here, just change your css as given below :

```
#photo-container img {
    /* filter: url(filters.svg#grayscale); Firefox 3.5+ */
    filter: gray; /* IE5+ */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Webkit Nightlies & Chrome Canary */
    -webkit-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;  
}
#photo-container img:hover {
     filter: none;
     -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
     -webkit-transform: scale(1.01);
}
```

In css given above, I'm applying css to all img tags contained within the div element having 'photo-container' Id. you can do the same by applying ID or class to img tag. But in that case, you need to change you need to change your css.

Hope this will help!